# Can I use localhost URL as Webhook URL in Instamojo?

Tags: webhooks, instamojo

I am implementing instamojo payment method into my website. Can I use a localhost URL as Webhook URL in order to test the process?

Comment: Use a local tunneling service like ngrok.com

Comment: Use https://ngrok.com/ !.its very easy to use.and resolves some problems of localtunnel.
using ngrok ucan tunnel your localhost and test your webhooks very easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't use localhost or  as Webhook URL.If it is used the following error will show "Domain name should not be "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" ". So it must be a live URL.

Answer (score 7):

I'm from Instamojo.

You can't use a local URL. This is because a webhook request is a POST request that is made from our server. Therefore, the only URLs that we can make these requests to would be URLs that are publicly available.

For testing purposes, I would recommend using [RequestBin](https://requestbin.com/). You can create a new bin and paste the URL for that bin in the webhook URL field of your Instamojo link. This will give you a link that is accessible by our server and you can inspect the POST requests to this link by appending `?inspect` at the end of the URL.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to forward Instamojo's webhooks to your local machine using tools like `localtunnel`.

- `npm` is required to install localtunnel. [[How to install node and npm]](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node)
- Install
  [localtunnel](https://localtunnel.me/)

Suppose you are running your local server at port 8000, in a new terminal window, execute this:

- `lt --port 8000`

It will show you output like:

- `your url is: https://whawgpctcs.localtunnel.me`

This is a *temporary* webhook URL that will forward every HTTPS request sent to `https://whawgpctcs.localtunnel.me` to your local server running on port `8000`.

- Paste this temporary url into Instamojo's webhook field and continue testing.
- **Remember to remove the temporary webhook URL from Instamojo once you are done testing**

The temporary webhook URL is valid as long as the `lt --port 8000` command (and your Internet connection) is active.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if you can use local host URL
but instead you can create new links, as below
https://www.instamojo.com/api/1.1/links/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the localhost URL as a webhook URL in order to test the process. But you can simply bypass it, open hosts file from `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`
At the end of the line write

```
127.0.0.1      yourname.com
```

And access localhost using yourname.com.
Just change localhost/your-location url with yourname.com/your-location in the PHP file.